# IP fragmentation cause Checksum incorrect message

Tags: c#, packet, packet-sniffers, pcap.net

I am using `PcapDorNet` DLLs and i try to fragment my traffic:

```
private IEnumerable<Packet> SplitPacket(Packet packet, int numberOfFragments)
        {
            IpV4Datagram ipV4Datagram = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
            Datagram datagram = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload;
            TransportLayer transportlayer = GetTransportLayer(packet);
            if (transportlayer != null)
            {
                EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
                ILayer layer = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
                IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
                ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
                DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;                
                PayloadLayer payload = (PayloadLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer(); //extract the data

                int totalLength = payload.Length;
                int partialLength = totalLength / numberOfFragments; //split data into smaller segments
                partialLength = (partialLength / 8) * 8; //make sure it's divisible with 8
                if (partialLength == 0)
                    partialLength = 8;
                //(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Fragmentation_and_reassembly)
                ushort offset = 0; //send one by one

                while (offset < totalLength)
                {
                    int fragmentLength = partialLength; //get length for this fragment
                    IpV4FragmentationOptions options = IpV4FragmentationOptions.MoreFragments;

                    if (offset + fragmentLength >= totalLength) //is this the last fragment ? trim length if needed
                    {
                        options = IpV4FragmentationOptions.None;
                        fragmentLength = totalLength - offset;
                    }

                    byte[] newBuffer = ipV4Datagram.Payload.ToArray(); //copy the actual data into a new buffer
                    PayloadLayer newPayload = new PayloadLayer { Data = new Datagram(newBuffer, offset, fragmentLength) };
                    ipV4Layer.Fragmentation = new IpV4Fragmentation(options, offset); //change IP layer fragmentation options
                    transportlayer.Checksum = null;
                    yield return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, transportlayer, newPayload);
                    offset += (ushort)fragmentLength; //next offset
                }
            }
        }
```

My input packet is `TCP packet` and the output is 4 packets: 3 `IPv4 packets` and the last is `TCP` but this packet i received is show under TCP layer field this message:

> Checksum: 0x5d17 [incorrect, should be 0xabb7 (maybe caused by "TCP
>   checksum offload"?)]

with UDP it seems that also every UDP packet split into several IPv4 packet and the last one is UDP but in UDP case it look fine.
I am i doing something wrong ?

Please see the original packet and the fragmentation: http://www.filedropper.com/desktop_122

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a very similar question in [Pcap.Net site](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/578375) with corrections to the code.

I believe following the advice there would help solve your issues.